# Series not showing in TeeChart when created at runtime?

Tags: delphi, teechart

I have a dataset which returns data like below

**Date, Area, Sales**

01/01/2017, Canteen, 1000
01/01/2017, Gym, 3000
01/01/2017, Salon, 2000
02/01/2017, Canteen, 5000
02/01/2017, Gym, 6000
02/01/2017, Salon, 7000

I am trying to create a stacked bar chart using this data

The number of series will be different

I have the logic below to create the series, but I am not sure how to add each value, e.g. I need the X Axis to be by date and have 2 bars.  Each bar is then stacked with 3 series, as per the above data.

```
while not tblSalesBreakdownByDate.Eof do
begin
  nIndex := objList.IndexOf(tblSalesBreakdownByDateCategory.AsString);
  if nIndex = -1  then
  begin
    objSeries := TBarSeries.Create(Self);
    objSeries.MultiBar := TMultiBar.mbStacked;
    objSeries.Title := tblSalesBreakdownByDateCategory.AsString;

    chrtBreakdownByDate.SeriesList.Add(objSeries);
    objList.AddObject(objSeries.Title, objSeries)
  end
  else
    objSeries := objList.Objects[nIndex];

  objSeries.Add(tblSalesBreakdownByDateTotalSales.AsFloat, tblSalesBreakdownByDateTransactionDate.AsString);

  tblSalesBreakdownByDate.Next;
end;
```

When I run this, although it doesnt crash I dont see any of the series I have added?

Can anyone see what is wrong?

Is there an easy way to do this?

Ideally I would have preferred to have used a DB Chart but I am not sure how to do that given the data is not static?

Cheers

Paul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
chrtBreakdownByDate.SeriesList.Add(objSeries);
```

call [**AddSeries**](http://www.teechart.net/docs/teechart/vclfmx/lib/html/TCustomAxisPanel.AddSeries.html) method:

```
chrtBreakdownByDate.AddSeries(objSeries);
```

or without any addition method call set the [**ParentChart**](http://www.teechart.net/docs/teechart/vclfmx/lib/html/TCustomChartElement.ParentChart.html) to the series:

```
objSeries.ParentChart := chrtBreakdownByDate;
```

The [**SeriesList**](http://www.teechart.net/docs/teechart/vclfmx/lib/html/TCustomAxisPanel.SeriesList.html) collection doesn't listen to collection changes, hence the series was not added to the chart. Examples of how to add series at runtime you can find on the [**TChart**](http://www.teechart.net/docs/teechart/vclfmx/lib/html/TChart.html) reference page.

Comment: For DBChart I guess you would need to have separate datasets for each series, which is dataset per Area in your case.

Comment: That sounds nasty at run time lol!  I may have to go that way though as this is not working when using a standard chart (different problem)

Comment: Well, DBChart data binding is for series (to the series `DataSource` property you assign dataset and to its `YValues.ValueSource` property field for which you want to display values). Maybe you could order your dataset by date and area to get groups that I think you want to have.